# How do you correctly await multiple asynchronous methods in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I recently starting developing in flutter.
When starting my app I first want to load Data from different sources.
I am having trouble with this and it seems like I haven't understood async / await yet.

**What I want to do**

When starting my App I want to load Data from multiple Sources. This should be done parallel but should only continue once all data sources are fully loaded.

**What I tried**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AsyncTester extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AsyncTesterState createState() => _AsyncTesterState();
}

class _AsyncTesterState extends State<AsyncTester> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startApplication();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  void startApplication() async {
    await loadData();
    print("starting Application!");
  }

  loadData() {
    loadDataSource1();
    loadDataSource2();
  }

  void loadDataSource1() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    print("Data Source 1 loaded.");
  }

  void loadDataSource2() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    print("Data Source 2 loaded.");
  }
}
```

The output is:

> I/flutter (23100): starting Application!
> I/flutter (23100): Data Source 2 loaded.
> I/flutter (23100): Data Source 1 loaded.

I don't understand why startApplication() does not wait for loadData() to finish.
I thought that is exactly what await does?

BTW I am nesting loadDataSource1() and loadDataSource2() in loadData() because doing this

```
void startApplication() async {
   await loadDataSource1();
   await loadDataSource2();
   print("starting Application!");
}
```

would load the Data after one another.
Is this correct or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In `loadData()` function, you need to `await` for the other calls in order to pause the program execution until a Future with value is returned

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `Future.wait`, this method will execute both of your asynchronous operation in parallel and will complete once they are all finished:

```dart
void startApplication() async {
  await Future.wait([
    loadDataSource1(),
    loadDataSource2(),
  ]);
  print("starting Application!");
}
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: `Future.wait` waits for multiple asynchronous operations *concurrently*.  Whether they execute in *parallel* depends on the implementation of those asynchronous operations.

Comment: True, in the example shown above it would be in parallel but as you've said it might varies depending on the operations.

Comment: Thanks! Mind explaining why my implementation does not work? In my mind await load Data() should finish before the print statement gets executed.

Comment: You need to make your method loadData asynchronous and make an await inside it.

Comment: So await someMethod() only awaits other await statements in someMethod()?